# How to open the redirected output file of a running script?

Tags: powershell

I have the following code in script `my.ps1`.

```
....
$attach = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment("c:\my.log")
$msg.Attachments.Add( $attach )
```

And I want to schedule it running as `powershell "& { my.ps1 > c:\my.log }"`.

However, I got the following error.

> New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "The process cannot access the file 'c:\my.log' because it is being used by another process."

Is anyway to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using redirection is locking the file. Instead you will need to remove the redirection and write to the file directly in the script using cmdlets like Out-File or Add-Content.

Comment: is it possible to put a group of scripts in a `{ ... }` and `tee` the output to file?

Comment: I would doubt it. I suspect that if you do anything to redirect the output of the script to a file, that file will be locked as long as the file is running.